# Outlook Mobile Add-ins for IMAP connected clients

Tags: mobile, outlook

I need an Outlook add-in for both Desktop and Mobile and my company uses IMAP for email. But according to the official overview in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-requirements, Outlook Add-ins is not supported for IMAP connected clients. So I've searched a little bit and found VSTO for desktop. It seems okay for now but I found out that it is only for desktop. Hence, I need a way to build an add-in for Outlook mobile which can be used by IMAP connected clients.

Comment: JS addins are Exchange only, your won't be able to use them in the desktop, iOS, or Android version of Outlook against an IMAP4 mailbox. COM addins (VSTO is just a framework) work in the Windows version of Outlook against all mailboxes.

Comment: Okay, thanks for info. What about mobile side of Outlook. Is there a way to build an add-in.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned - iOS, and Android. Only against an Exchange mailbox.